# Get the data-target dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the follwing link:

```
<a href="edit/2" class="popup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productVariantModal"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
```

I would like to get the data-target dynamically so I could reuse my javescript code.

I have tried something like this:

```
  var target = $(this).closest('[data-target]');
```

But this does't work.

Any Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: do you need the ID right ?

Comment: @samitha no. I want the value of data-target.

Comment: @sanders .attr('data-target') not working dynamically?

Comment: you wan to get on click of it??

Comment: What do you mean by "get the data-target"? Get the value of the data-target attribute? The contents of some DOM element with an ID set in the data-target attribute? Also curious about the meaning of "reuse my javascript code."

Comment: can you share your code on fiddle? it easy but want to know how and why you are doing ?

Comment: look at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9FStK/ You about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `#productVariantModal` right ? So.Simple use `attr`

```
var getValue = $('.popup').attr("data-target");
```

if it dynamically

```
var getValue = $(this).attr("data-target");
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pK3kL/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
var target = $(this).closest('[data-target]');
```

should be this:

```
var target =$('.popup').data('target');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using this in the callback of some event fired by that hyperlink, to get the value of the data you can do:

`$(this).data('target')`